# scan ean13 with iphone / android

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, barcode, zxing

I've already used zxing in the past to scan qr-codes with Android and iPhone devices. These apps were made with PhoneGap and a Zxing plugin for PhoneGap.

As far as i know, only a QR-decoder is availible for the iPhone/PhoneGap.

I need a library which can be used with PhoneGap. So for both the Android and iPhone devices to decode an EAN13 barcode.

Is there such a library available these days?

Comment: AFAIK EAN_13 should be supported on both platforms; https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner and https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner .

Comment: @harism Thanks, looks promising. I guess i have a slightly older version which didn't supported EAN at that time.

Comment: ZXing support for 1D codes in C++ (and, by extension, Objective C) is not enabled by default. See the question "Why don't 1D codes work on iOS devices?" in the ZXing FAQ (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As harism said the BarcodeScanner plugin on iOS and Android supports EAN_13:

[Android: Barcode Scanner plugin for Phonegap](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner)
[iPhone: Barcode Scanner plugin for Phonegap](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner)

My team member fixed up some of the issues in the iPhone BarcodeScanner.